# problems with jquery form validation code

Tags: jquery, forms

I am trying to create a form validation script. Everything that I have done so far is below and hopefully self-explanatory, it's not very complex. However, I am having one problem, which is that it won't submit the form when a valid e-mail is entered.

In summary, what's happening is this:

(1) When nothing is entered, the invalid class is added fine and form doesn't submit.

(2) When an invalid e-mail is entered, the invalid class is added fine and form doesn't submit.

(3) When a valid e-mail is entered, the form does nothing and does not submit the valid entry.

Can anyone see anything in the code that might be causing this and offer a remedy?

Thank you

```
$(function(){

var emailbox, emailval, emailreg, pcount;
    emailbox = $('#e-mail');
    emailval = $('#e-mail').val();
    emailreg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    pcount = 0;

    $('form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        if (emailval === '' || emailval === ' ') {
            emailbox.addClass('invalid');
            pcount += 1;
        }

        if (!emailreg.test(emailval)) {
            emailbox.addClass('invalid');
            pcount += 1;
        }

        if (pcount === 0) {
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you considered [`jquery.validate`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)?

Comment: No, I'm trying to learn jQuery and am trying to write as much as possible myself..

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
        if (emailval === '' || emailval === ' ') {
            emailbox.addClass('invalid');
            return false;
        }

        if (!emailreg.test(emailval)) {
            emailbox.addClass('invalid');
            return false;
        }
});
```